# Resetting DB connection in Spring boot at runtime after getting connection closed

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, database-connection

I am getting error `connection reset` in my running spring boot app for db2 database. On restarting the application the connection starts working.
If I receive `connection closed` or `connection reset` error, I need to reconnect to the database at runtime.

What will be the best way to do this?
I am using Hikari connection pool , Is there some property which allows the database connection to be checked ..if broken ..then reconnect.
Or some spring boot configuration like @RefreshScope recreates the bean after configuration changes. Any spring boot bean which might help in this case?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Enable idle connection validation.

Comment: Thanks .. I wanted to know like in spring boot we have the property @RefreshScope property to automatically re create the bean in case of configuration changes. Is there something available for closed connections ? Or I need to write my own methods which checks if the connection is closed then again create the database connection.

Comment: As stated, enable connection validation for idle connections.

Comment: Hi M. Deinum, thanks for the reply.. I have set idleTimeout as 120000 & maxLifetime as 130000, ConnectionTmeout as 300000.. Still getting connection marked as broken exception. How do I enable idle connection validation? My driver supports jdbc4, so didn't set the validation query

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, I try config param for hiraki but still getting connection is closed.
You can try the way by this link https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/spring-boot-retry-database-connection-startup-abdelghani-roussi?articleId=6723332249346981888